# Earned reputation without any reason

Tags: support

Today, I earned **6 reputation** points **without any clear reason**.

There was green notification **6** in top of *stackoverflow*, and my reputation increased from `444` to `450`.

There is no earning of **6** reputation history.

Can this be a bug in Stackoverflow?

Comment: Maybe a rep recalc?

Comment: Maybe you got 6 answer-downvotes refunded after the post has been deleted?

Comment: @Sumurai8 That may be the reason. One of my question received downvotes, and now the question is gone. But I should have got notified that my question is deleted by *someone* for *some reason*?

Comment: I am honestly not sure :-| If your answer gets deleted, I think you still can see the auto-comments that the review queue leaves you. If the question gets deleted you answered upon I don't know. *looks around* Where is a mod when you need their knowledge?

Comment: Have you tried clicking "show removed posts" if you have a recently deleted question?

Comment: Do we have a canonical one of these questions on Meta.SO? (I see at least one other question that also answered by clicking on the checkbox)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[A question you wrote that was negatively scored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219720/framework-vs-cms) was removed during an automatic cleanup process, which refunded the points that you lost from the down-votes.

In your [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2178351/barun?tab=reputation) there's a little check box that says "Show removed posts" that would have made this easier to spot.

We don't show it by default because shoving deleted content at you in a place where folks normally go to bask in their awesomeness isn't, well, practical.